# Renaming files in linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I have 2 files

```
2014-06-27 names.csv 
2014-06-27 money.csv
```

I want to rename the files and do something with them.

Can i do this with the rename command? how should i do it? is there a better way?

I can't use a predefined length of characters to chop off at the beginning as the automatically generated files may have a different prefix scheme on some later date. but onething is for sure. They will always end in " names.csv" and " money.csv"

EDIT: I want to rename them as "names.csv" and "money.csv". So sorry for not providing this info

Comment: What should they be renamed to?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I've edited the question

Comment: how it would be possible if more than one file ends with names.csv?

Comment: one file is named "2014-06-27 names.csv" tomorrow it may be named "2014-06-28 names.csv" . Regardless what the prefix before the word "name" in the file name is I want to change the name of the file to "names.csv". Ideally there is only file to convert in the folder

Comment: so there must one file ended with `names.csv`, and like wise. You want to remove the part before the last space.

Comment: well in this case yes. But in reality i want to remove everything before 'names' in the old csv

Comment: Tomorrow if the replace the space with an underscore it still has to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `rename` command:

```
rename 's/^.* (.*\.csv)$/$1/' *.csv
```

Comment: they won't both be in the folder at the same time Avinash.

Comment: 34 money.csv should be converted as soon as it is created and then moved from this folder. so that when 42 money.csv comes in it will be the only csv file in the folder

Comment: So this `rename` would work for you right?

Comment: anubhava, it does work for me right now. but if the character immediately before names changed from space to # or something i would have to modify this script.

Comment: You can use a character class like `[ #@]` ingress of space on this regex to match all these cases.